# Unsure if I have understood Hydra syntax correctly?

Tags: brute-force

So, when I see the Hydra help file, this is what it says:

`Syntax: hydra [[[-l LOGIN|-L FILE] [-p PASS|-P FILE]] | [-C FILE]] [-e nsr] [-o FILE] [-t TASKS] [-M FILE [-T TASKS]] [-w TIME] [-W TIME] [-f] [-s PORT] [-x MIN:MAX:CHARSET] [-SuvVd46] [service://server[:PORT][/OPT]]`

The service I am interested in is `http-get-form`. When I look at the help for this module, I need to use the module like this:

`<url>:<form parameters>:<condition string>[:<optional>[:<optional>]`

From the examples that the help file provides, I need to use it like so -

`"/login.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:incorrect"`

I construct a query like so -

`hydra -L usernames.txt -P passwords.txt http-get-form://site.appspot.com "/lab/webapp/1:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Failed"`

Hydra fails with the error `Unknown service: lab/webapp/1:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Failed`

Looking at this post [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37020/why-does-hydra-return-16-valid-passwords-when-none-are-valid), it may be that Hydra no longer support that syntax form. I know that there is an alternate syntax that I could use which works. However, I would like to know what I am doing wrong with the syntax that I am using.

Comment: I haven't really used Hydra, but why do you put the path in quotes? Maybe try: http-get-form://site.appspot.com/lab/webapp/1:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Failed
Or try & write http://site.... instead.

Comment: @user1622951 It returns `[ERROR] Wrong syntax, requires three arguments separated by a colon which may not be null: /lab/webapp/1`

Comment: I'm confused. You have a syntax that works and an indication that hydra changed their syntax, but you still want to know why the old syntax doesn't work?

Comment: @schroeder The confusion stems from the fact that the 'old syntax may not work' is something I read from a source I cant explicitly connect with Hydra. The Hydra help file shows this as the only syntax. So, I am not too sure if this syntax is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess syntax description is correct for `http` service only :)

Change your command line into this, and will do the trick. I have tested on 8.1 version

```
hydra -L usernames.txt -P passwords.txt site.appspot.com http-get-form "/lab/webapp/1:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Failed"
```